# Passar url de vídeo para dentro de Modal - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou passando a url para dentro da embed (**#meuid**) assim:

```
<script>
   $('#treinamentos').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
       var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
       var nome   = button.data('nome') 
       var video  = button.data('video') 

       $('#nmTreinamento').text(nome);   
       $('#meuid').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaKvZzKyI1s');
    })
</script>
```

A modal com a `embed` pega a url mas não exibe o vídeo:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="treinamentos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="alterarLabel" style="z-index: 1100;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Deseja excluir o Treinamento ? </h4>
             </div>

             <div class="modal-body">

              <label for="nmTreinamento" id="nmTreinamento"></label>

             <embed id='meuid' 
             type="application/x-shockwave-flash" fs=1
             allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"
             width="940" height="440" align="center"></embed>               
            </div>                
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Existe uma forma de passar a url para dentro do embed?

Comment: Passar uma variavel do js pra uma do php? É isso?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert não me atende essa resposta

Comment: Bia, "O PHP corre do lado do servidor para criar a página, e o JS corre do lado do cliente com a página já criada. A unica maneira deles "falarem" é via **ajax**." esta na resposta daquela pergunta, ou seja você tera de implementar um solução Ajax :D.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert não me expressei bem, mudei a pergunta para explicar o que realmente desejo fazer. De qualquer forma obrigada.

Comment: Bia, a sinalização é "**possível** duplicata". O procedimento correto é editar a pergunta para mostrar que não é o caso, idealmente até incluindo no seu texto *"Li a [pergunta duplicata](/#) e não serve por tal-e-tal motivo"*

Comment: @brasofilo informei antes de editar, mas não saiu.

Comment: É só porque a pergunta tem 4 votos para fechar como duplicata e algum desavisado que não ler os comentários pode dar o voto final equivocadamente...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o próprio jquery.
Coloque o id nas tag's necessário, por exemplo:

```
<embed id='meuid' src="https://www.youtube.com/v/<?=$video?>?version=3"
                 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" fs=1
                 allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"
                 width="940" height="440" align="center"></embed>
```

Use a função `attr` do jquery para alterar a propriedade src da tag acima.

```
$minhaurl = 'meu link formatado com o id aqui'
$('#meuid').attr('src', $minhaurl)
```

Qualquer dúvida pode perguntar.

Comment: dessa forma o vídeo não é exibido

Comment: Consegui usar oque me passou, só coloquei o embed dentro de um object e passei o valor para esse object:
  $('#object').attr('value', 'https://www.youtube.com/v/url?version=3"')
  $('#embed').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/v/url?version=3"')

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo a documentação disponível no [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp) :

> Uma animação flash embutido

Ou seja creio que `<embed>` so da suporte a arquivos `.swf` local.

[Sobre vídeos do Youtube](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp)

A solução que encontrei foi por `<iframe>`.

```js
$('#meuid').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/VaKvZzKyI1s');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe width="420" height="315" id="meuid">
</iframe>
```

#### Obs

Note que há uma alteração a ser feita :

`www.youtube.com/`**`watch?v=`**`VaKvZzKyI1s`
`www.youtube.com/`**`embed/`**`VaKvZzKyI1s`

Para isso você pode fazer por `replace`:

```
function changeToEmbed(src){
    return src.replce('watch?v=', 'embed/');
}
```

Comment: sua resposta também foi útil, usei o www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaKvZzKyI1s